# trying to close window in tkinter but showing following error

Tags: python, tkinter, button

```
def close(root):
    root.destroy()
```

```
submit1= Button(root ,text ="Submit",bg="Green",font = ('Comic Sas MS',20,'bold'),borderwidth=0,padx=20,pady=10,border=1)
submit1.place(relx=0.4,rely=0.5)
exit =Button(root,text ="Exit",command = close(root),bg="Red",borderwidth=0,padx=20,pady=10,font = ('Comic Sas MS',20,'bold'),border=1)
exit.place(relx=0.6,rely=0.5)
```

i am trying to destroy whole window but its giving me error like

> can't invoke "button" command: application has been destroyed

what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Remove the root parameter and try

Comment: You basically destroyed the root when invoking the button.

Comment: @Sujay: they destroyed the root when _creating_ the button.

Comment: @BryanOakley I am unable to post new questions may I know why ?

Comment: I have no idea. Have you checked your email or profile to see if there are any messages from admins or moderators?

Comment: @BryanOakley ok sir. can you please upvote my any post? because that might help me.